# uplodify upload (File Upload) is not working in Update Panel?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I have a aspx suppose Page1.aspx in that I I am registering a web User Control suppose Page2.ascx in that same Page2.ascx I am registering an other web user control suppose Page3.ascx in which I have a file upload in which I am using Uplodifyupload for uploading multiple images. I am keeping fileupload inside the update panel. I have a datalist on Page2.ascx i am binding all the uploaded image in datalist. datalist is also inside the update panel. when I am clicking on any item of datalist Browser button is not showing for the first time its working but after clicking on item its not even showing.

Page3.ascs:

here I have uplodifyupload JS

```
  <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Always">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div>
       <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server"/>
    </div> 

  </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Page2.ascx

```
 <test:fileUpload ID="testupload" runat="server" /> // I am not keeping it in updatepanel.
```

how to solve my prob. so that on every click browser btn can be shown and for the user page should be stable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot upload files using AJAX. You will have to move the FileUpload control outside of the UpdatePanel as it interferes with the file upload attempting to send the file in the AJAX request which is not possible. When you use Uploadify, it's up to you to write the javascript that will upload the file to the server, not rely on UpdatePanel. On the server you will need to have a generic ASHX handler or a dedicated ASPX page that will receive the file upload along with any additional parameters that you might need.

Comment: If I am not using Update Panel then its working fine.. I am using Uplodify upload... I already mention in qus.

Comment: @Rocky, you will have to move it out of the UpdatePanel. It interferes with the file upload as it attempts to send it as an AJAX request which is not possible.

Comment: use async method of the uploadcontrol in AJAX control tool kit